# Can I convert an BND object into an RDS object in R?

Tags: r, polygon, mapping, polygon-creation

I have a general question which is likely to be silly one: is it possible to convert a .bnd object into an .rds object?

Briefly, I want to analyze the map in the R package `spBayesSurv`:

```
library(spBayesSurv)
library(R2BayesX)

data("LeukSurv")

# Map object
nwengland <- read.bnd(system.file("otherdata/nwengland.bnd",
                                  package = "spBayesSurv"))
```

but the methods I want to use only work with .rds files, and the map is only available in .bnd format.

I can transform this map into sp map

```
nwsp = bnd2sp(nwengland)
```

but I need to apply the command `polys.setup()` (R package GJRM) to the map, which requires an .rds object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help for `?hiv` shows that `polys.setup` doesn't require an RDS file, it requires an R object created from reading in these particular RDS files. RDS files are R's native data storage and can store any R objects:

```
 # obj <- readRDS("ZMB_adm1.rds") 
 # ## RDS Zambian Level 1 file obtained from 
 # ## http://www.gadm.org. 
 #
 # pol <- polys.setup(obj)
```

In this case, the GADM data files are `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` objects, with names of the various regions.

When converted, the `bnd` object is a `SpatialPolygons` object:

```
> nwsp = bnd2sp(nwengland)
> nwsp
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 24 
extent      : -0.004, 0.832, -0.047, 1.077  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA
```

Feed this to `polys.setup` and it complains:

```
> pol = polys.setup(nwsp)
Error in object$NAME_0 : no $ method for object without attributes
```

because it only stores the polygon geometry, not the names. Let's create a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with some names:

```
> nwspd = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr=nwsp, data=data.frame(NAME_0=paste0("X",1:length(nwsp))))

> class(nwspd)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

and you can convert this using `polys.setup`:

```
> nwsp.pol = polys.setup(nwspd)
Regions defined for each Polygons
```

Whether this is sufficient for your further processing I don't know, its possible the code expects other names on the regions as well. The `bnd` file doesn't contain any region names or other data.

Comment: Many thanks. I still need to check if the methods will work, but this perfectly answers my question.